# NSString.toString returns null-terminated string

Tags: ios, nsstring, nativescript, null-terminated

In Nativescript I have a plugin that use NSString methods and I want to return a javascript String. If I run `nsstringInstance.toString()` I get a null-terminated javascript string. I can work around it by removing all \0-characters from the end of the string. Is there a better way to do it?

```
function base64_decode(base64string) {
    let nsdata = NSData.alloc().initWithBase64EncodedStringOptions(base64string, opts);
    return NSString.alloc().initWithDataEncoding(nsdata, NSUTF8StringEncoding).toString();
}
```

I can fix this by using this

```
let decoded = base64_decode("SOME BASE64 STRING").replace(/\0+$/,'');
```

Is this the only way, or is there a NSString method to return UTF-8 string that is not null-terminated?

Answer (score 0):

`.toString()` is not a valid method in `NSString` instance. Try `.UTF8String`

Comment: .toString is available in NativeScript (as toString is available on all JS objects). Will UTF8String return a javascript string without null-termination?

Comment: My first attemps was without the toString call, which returned an NSString instance which is unusable with javascript's string functions (I want to send it into JSON.parse after decoding it). JSON.decode compains about the last character which is a null byte (\0)